# Possible iOS Bug with VoiceOver and Onscreen keyboard use

Tags: ios, ios5, bug-reporting

I found what I believe to be a bug in iOS 5.1. It seems like it's specifically on 4S devices. I was really hoping some other iOS developers with Wireless keyboards could test this out. If you find that it is a problem, please submit it as a bug report. This particular issue is very important to a project I'm working on and I would appreciate any community support on this issue.

**The Bug Report:**

This bug allows the on-screen keyboard to appear even when the Apple Wireless Keyboard is connected (without any prompting from the keyboard's eject key). The problem occurs after the keyboard has been paired and VoiceOver is activated.

Steps to Reproduce:

Make sure that VoiceOver can be turned on via tripple pressing the home key. VoiceOver should be turned off initially. Pair the keyboard to the iPhone 4s running iOS 5.1. Turn the keyboard off so that the on-screen keyboard is the only form of text input. Do the following:

1. Enter any app's text field (I was able to reproduce the bug on the home screen's "Search iPhone" search bar).
2. Turn the wireless keyboard on. The on-screen keyboard should disappear as it's supposed to.
3. Tripple press the home button to activate voiceover. The on-screen keyboard comes back.

Expected Results:

The on-screen keyboard should not appear.

Actual Results:

The on-screen keyboard appears and keeps appearing every time another text field is accessed (regardless of being connected to the wireless keyboard).

Regression:

iOS 5.1 on iPhone 4s

Notes:

If step 1 is taken with VoiceOver initially turned on, then step 2 will still happen as it is described. From that point, if VoiceOver is turned off, the on-screen keyboard does not return so long as the wireless keyboard is connected.

This bug makes designing apps to work specifically with the wireless keyboard and VoiceOver very difficult. The on-screen keyboard appears at inappropriate times and consequently gets in the way of VoiceOver's sequential screen navigation as well as gesture recognition.